# how to solve error: MQSCO wrong size error in pymqi

Tags: ibm-mq, mq, pymqi

we use an old pymqi version and now we want to upgrade to 1.10.1 version.

after installing the new files,
we get an error while trying to connect_with_option.

the error is: MQSCO wrong size. Given 560, expected 544
(we use linux, 64 bit)

Do you know what can cause this error?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show your code using the MQSCO please

Comment: @reut, I think your code uses previous version of pymqe.so (builded by previous pymqi installation). Please check paths

Comment: Did you compile?

Comment: As you may have already downloaded and installed pymqi, you will have also built `pymqe.so`. The problem with pip, is that it caches, and will have cached `pymqe.so` .  When you try an install, pip will check its cache first and copy, including copying a previously built `pymqe.so`, rather than download and install. Try `pip install --no-cache-dir pymqi`.

Comment: @chughts I tried, but still the problem exists.
I use mq 7.5, can it cause this problem?

Comment: If you are using the latest version of the client toolkit then it shouldn't be a problem, but the size of the SCO has increased over releases.  `cmcc.h` shows 5 different sizes for MQSCO. Which version of the client toolkit have you downloaded? You will find `cmcc.h` in the `\inc` directory.